# Find a formula for the general term $a_n$ of the sequence, assuming that the pattern of the first few terms continues.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\{4, -2, 4, -2, \dots\}$

$a_n = ?$

What is the formula for the general term $a_n$ of the sequence?

I know that it starts in the numerator with $(-1)^{n-1}$ in order to alternate between positive and negative, but I can't seem to figure out the rest.

The homework problem I am working on requires it to be a non-piecewise function.

Comment: Why not use a piecewise definition? Such as, assuming your first term is $a_1$:

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
4 & n \text{ is odd } \\
-2 & n \text{ is even }
\end{cases}$$

Sure, you could just try to write it as some function $a_n = f(n)$, but any such definition will just be equivalent to the above. Just a clever rewriting that's less intuitive/easy to use.

Comment: This is not  a valid question in Mathematics.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer the online homework problem I am working on requires it to be a non-piecewise function. It won't accept a repititon such as {4, -2, 4, -2, ...} either.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=1-3\cdot(-1)^n$ works if you don't want a piecewise definition